# Why does assigning `xr.ones_like` to a DataSet variable change unrelated coordinates?

Tags: python, python-xarray

When I assign the result of `xr.ones_like` to a Dataset variable, I lose some of my data assigned to coordinates:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

A, B, C = 2, 3, 4

ds = xr.Dataset()
ds.coords['source'] = (['a', 'b', 'c'], np.random.random((A, B, C)))
ds.coords['unrelated'] = (['a', 'c'], np.random.random((A, C)))

print('INITIAL:', ds['unrelated'], '\n')

# do 'ones_like' manually
ds['dest-1'] = (['a', 'b'], np.ones((A, B)))

print('AFTER dest-1:', ds['unrelated'], '\n')

ds['dest-2'] = xr.ones_like(ds['source'].isel(c=0))

print('AFTER dest-2:', ds['unrelated'], '\n')
```

Output:

```
INITIAL: <xarray.DataArray 'unrelated' (a: 2, c: 4)>
array([[0.185851, 0.962589, 0.772985, 0.570292],
       [0.905792, 0.865125, 0.412361, 0.666977]])
Coordinates:
    unrelated  (a, c) float64 0.1859 0.9626 0.773 0.5703 0.9058 0.8651 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: a, c

AFTER dest-1: <xarray.DataArray 'unrelated' (a: 2, c: 4)>
array([[0.185851, 0.962589, 0.772985, 0.570292],
       [0.905792, 0.865125, 0.412361, 0.666977]])
Coordinates:
    unrelated  (a, c) float64 0.1859 0.9626 0.773 0.5703 0.9058 0.8651 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: a, c

AFTER dest-2: <xarray.DataArray 'unrelated' (a: 2)>
array([0.185851, 0.905792])
Coordinates:
    unrelated  (a) float64 0.1859 0.9058
Dimensions without coordinates: a
```

Why did `unrelated` lose a dimension after using `xr.ones_like`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that this behavior looks like [a bug](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2068). Assigning variables definitely shouldn't modify existing coordinates, without some sort of explicit opt-in.

This appears to be caused by `xr.ones_like(ds['source'].isel(c=0))` having a different value for the coordinate `'unrelated'`, which is (incorrectly) overriding the exist coordinating. So as a work-around, you could drop this extra coordinate before assigning it to `ds['dest-2']`, e.g., with

```
ds['dest-2'] = xr.ones_like(ds['source'].isel(c=0)).drop('unrelated')
```

or

```
ds['dest-2'] = xr.ones_like(ds['source'].isel(c=0)).reset_coords(drop=True)
```

Comment: Oh *thank goodness!*  This is what I basically suspected was happening, but I feared it was intentional! =P